# How to properly set padding for QListView::item using Qt style sheets?

Tags: c++, qt5, qlistview, qtwidgets

So I have following lines in my style sheet (among others):

```
QListView::item {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

and this breakes my list view appearance.

[image]

However, after clicking on one of the checkboxes, it fixes itself.

[image]

It works okay without padding specified. 
Any ideas?

Comment: @Miki I'm expecting items to be displayed as showed on the second image all the time.

Comment: seems padding is working on alternate rows. Are you doing something related to them in you stylesheet?

Comment: @Miki I've tried to disable alternate rows for this view and also have tried to delete all other QListView related style sheet code but this. Nothing helps. So it's rather not related to alternate rows, on my opinion.

Comment: @Miki not sure I got you right. Do you mean setting padding property to ::item for other elements? If so - then yes, it works okay for QTreeView::item for me. Also, note that padding **is** set for QListView::item in my example.

Comment: @Miki no problem :) I will try to upload some example later today.

Comment: is this issue resolved? would be nice to share the answer, really